# Import and Export Wizard SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Is there an feature on the Import/Export Wizard of SQL Server which allows me to do the following? If so, how can I go about it...

Before

```
+---------+-------------+----------+------+
|  Name   | Description | Delivery | Cost |
+---------+-------------+----------+------+
| dfdsf   | dfgdfgdf    |       34 |      |
| sdfsdgf | dfgdfgdf    |      324 |      |
| dfg     | dfgdfgdf    |       23 |      |
| dfgfdg  | gdf         |       43 |      |
| dfgdfg  | gdf         |       23 |      |
| fdgfdg  | fgd         |      443 |      |
+---------+-------------+----------+------+


+---------+-------------+----------+------+
|  Name   | Description | Delivery | Cost |
+---------+-------------+----------+------+
| dfdsf   | dfgdfgdf    |       34 |      |
| sdfsdgf | dfgdfgdf    |      324 |      |
| dfg     | dfgdfgdf    |       23 |      |
| dfgfdg  | gdf         |       43 |      |
| dfgdfg  | gdf         |       23 |      |
| fdgfdg  | fgd         |      443 |      |
|         |             |          |  324 |
|         |             |          |  324 |
|         |             |          |  234 |
|         |             |          |  234 |
|         |             |          |   23 |
|         |             |          |  423 |
+---------+-------------+----------+------+
```

So I have the table above:

- I want to add the cost column in from a Flat File (CSV source, made on Excel).
- Can I do this on the wizard without removing the other data - I have tried multiple different options on the wizard, but I seem to keep removing the data or the data added creates another set of row, so it will look like bottom table.

I do have a primary key on this table and I have set that to increase automatically by 1 - I have also got foreign keys, though I had to remove the relationships temporarily to allow me to even get the data onto the table.

**Sorry the formatting isn't clear - The top table represents my table and the bottom table shows what happens when I input data - What I want is a the cost column aligned with the old data.**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you matching the cost data to the existing data in the table? Does the primary key in the table have a matching key in your CSV file?

Comment: No, I have not tried that - My main table has a Primary Key ID. I will get back to you with what happens if I add Primary Key column in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update existing records in the table you need to be able to identify a relationship between the rows in your table and the rows in your CSV file.

To update the rows in the existing table import the CSV file into a separate table. Then run an UPDATE statement like the one below to update the rows in the existing table with the data from the new table.

```
UPDATE T
SET T.Cost = S.Cost
FROM dbo.MyTable AS T
    JOIN dbo.CsvInput AS S
        ON T.ID = S.ID
```